# Can this congruence be simplified?

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, congruences

$$p(p+1) \equiv -q(q+1) \bmod pq$$

Can this be reduced to an easier format?

Comment: Are p and q primes?

Comment: @martycohen Not necessarily

Comment: How about relatively prime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that 
$$p(p+1) + q(q+1) = p^2 + q^2 + p + q \equiv p^2 + 2 p q + q^2 + p + q \equiv (p+q)(p+q+1) \mod pq$$
so it's equivalent to 
$$ (p+q)(p+q+1) \equiv 0 \mod pq $$
Note also that $p+q+1 \equiv (p+1)(q+1) \mod pq$, so this is equivalent to
$$(p+q)(p+1)(q+1) \equiv 0 \mod pq$$

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that.

Comment: Not if  $\gcd(p+1, pq) > 1$.

Comment: If you factor $pq = P_1^{d_1} \ldots P_n^{d_n}$ where $P_1, \ldots, P_n$ are primes, then each $P_j^{d_j}$ must divide exactly one of $p+q$ and $p+q+1$.
In general some will divide $p+q$ and others will divide $p+q+1$, and $pq$ itself won't divide either.

Comment: For example, try $p = 6$, $q = 3$, $pq = 18$: $(p+q)(p+q+1) = 90 \equiv 0 \mod 18$, but $18$ doesn't divide either $p+q = 9$ or $p+q+1 = 10$.

Comment: I suspect there are only finitely many solutions for any fixed $p$, and for most $p$ there will be none.  The only solutions for $1 \le p \le q \le 1000$ are $$[p,q] =  [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 6], [3, 6], [6, 14], [6, 21], [14, 35], [21, 77], [35, 90], [90, 234], [77, 286], [234, 611]$$

Comment: Here's something interesting: it looks like each pair $(a(n),a(n+1))$ of consecutive terms in OEIS sequence A101265 (https://www.oeis.org/A101265) satisfy the condition, with $(p+q)(p+q+1)/(pq) = 6$

Comment: Also for consecutive terms in A032908, with $5$ instead of $6$.

Comment: ... and those seem to be all the solutions; at least, there are no others with $p+q \le 10^5$

Answer (score 0):

Mod $pq$,
$p(p+1) \equiv -q(q+1)
\iff
p^2+p = -q^2-q
\iff
p^2+q^2 +p+q =0
$

$\begin{array}\\
(p+q+1)^2
&\equiv
p^2+q^2+1+2pq+2p+2q\\
&\equiv
p^2+q^2+1+2p+2q\\
&\equiv
(p^2+q^2+p+q)+p+q+1\\
&\equiv
p+q+1\\
\end{array}
$

Therefore,
if $n = p+q+1$,
$n^2 \equiv n$
or
$n(n-1) \equiv 0
$.

If $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes
(or even just relatively prime),
then
$gcd(n-1, p) = gcd(n-1, q) = 1$,
so that
$n \equiv 0
$.

But $n < pq
$,
so that
this can not hold.