# Number Theory: Prove that $\gcd(a,b) \le \sqrt{a+b}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

> For positive integers $a$ and $b$, we know $\dfrac{a+1}{b} + \dfrac{b+1}{a}$ is also
>   a positive integer. Prove that $\gcd(a,b) \le \sqrt{a+b}$.

Using Bézout's lemma, we know that $\gcd(a, b) = sa + tb$. I want to prove that $(sa+tb)^2 \le a+b$. We know $ab\,|\,a(a+1) + b(b+1)$.

Therefore, $(sa + tb)^2 \le (sa)^2 + (tb)^2 + 2st(a(a+1)+b(b+1))$.

I'm not sure how can  continue from here. Any ideas to continue, or for a better way to prove the statement?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it suppose to be $(sa+tb)^2 \leq a+b$?

Comment: @Larry yes. fixed it.

Comment: A related question (not a duplicate nor an answer): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1417404/diophantine-equation-xyxy1-kxy-0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $d\mid a$, $d\mid b$.
Then 
$$n:=\left(\frac{a+1}b+\frac{b+1}a\right)\cdot \frac ad\cdot \frac bd-\frac{a^2}{d^2}-\frac{b^2}{d^2}$$ 
is an integer. Conclude.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 5):

Hagen von Eitzen does not seem to want to explain his answer further, so I will attempt to do so here:

Suppose that $d|a$ and $d|b$. Then we have the following:
\begin{align*}
\frac{a+b}{d^2} &= \frac{a^2+a}{d^2}+\frac{b^2+b}{d^2}-\frac{a^2}{d^2}-\frac{b^2}{d^2} \\ &=\left(\frac{a+1}{b}+\frac{b+1}{a}\right)\cdot\frac{a}{d}\cdot\frac{b}{d}-\frac{a^2}{d^2}-\frac{b^2}{d^2}
\end{align*}

The RHS is an integer by the hypothesis of the problem. The LHS is positive by the hypothesis of the problem. Thus we can safely conclude that $\frac{a+b}{d^2}\geq 1$ for all common divisors of $a$ and $b$, which is what we wanted to show.